# I am getting 404 while tying to reach my Rest-API with Nginx reverse_proxy

Tags: rest, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Rest-API running on my cloud server 8084 port. When I try to access mysitename:8084/swagger-ui.html, I can see the Api Documentation page of Swagger. But when I try this as mysitename.com/api/swagger-ui.html, I get a 404 error.

I read a lot of similar questions about this problem on StackOverflow, I tried different solutions but I could not succeeded.

Here is my nginx config file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/mysitename.com/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysitename.com www.mysitename.com;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name mysitename.com www.mysitename.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/petahr.access.log;

    location / {
      root /var/www/mysitename.com/html/;
      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name mysitename.com www.mysitename.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /api/ {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:8084/;
      proxy_read_timeout      90;

      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is `nginx -T` output

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -T
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "mysitename.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.mysitename.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: You seem to have two `server` blocks with the same `listen` and `server_name`. I suspect that the first of those is handling the request and the one with the reverse proxy is being ignored. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test your configuration and view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, thank you for your answer. It seems that you are right, I added the nginx -T output to my post. Can you help me with fixing this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration check confirms [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)'s comment. Just a warning that there are two server blocks with the same `listen` and `server_name`.

1) Try to transfer your `location /api/ {}` right below your `location / {}` block of the 2nd server block.

2) Remove the whole 3rd server block

3) If you wish to redirect from http to https, add `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` right at the end of your server block listening to port 80.

4) Run `nginx -T` again to check for errors.

5) Reload Nginx, if no errors were found.

Here's the suggested server block configuration file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/mysitename.com/html/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysitename.com www.mysitename.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name mysitename.com www.mysitename.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysitename.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/petahr.access.log;

    location / {
      root /var/www/mysitename.com/html/;
      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:8084/;
      proxy_read_timeout      90;

      ## try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much, for your helps :)

Comment: are both server blocks required or can i just use the first one and add location /api/ to it?

Comment: Hi @kd12345, each server block serves a different purpose. The first one is for accepting requests through port 80 (HTTP-only requests) while the second one accepts requests through port 443 (HTTPS requests). If you choose to use just the first one, your site will only be accessible like this: `http://mysitename.com` or `http://www.mysitename.com`, and if anyone tries to access your site in https, the browser will display an error. For development, using port 80 alone is okay. When going live, it's recommended to enable port 443 and auto-redirect from port 80 so visitors see https always

Comment: @johnsing thank you for this amazing explanation, appreciate it alot. another question please, so currently when i open my ipaddress in browser using http:// i get directed to index.nginx-debian.html instead of my / route declared in my nodejs server (which is ok i dont mind). But when i try to access ipaddress/api i keep getting Error 404.  how do i update the code above so that i can access my nodejs /api/ route from nginx?

Comment: @johnsing i only need this ip address for my API not to server and webpage